# VS Code Language Server Linting Incorrect

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, static-analysis, python-language-server

VS Code (and in particular the MS Python Language Server) shows lot's of unnecessary errors. 
These appear as it lints while I type, but then they persist afterwards.

For example, after typing `self.var = var`

```
[Python] 's' used before definition [use-before-def]
[Python] 'se' used before definition [use-before-def]
[Python] 'sel' used before definition [use-before-def]
```

These linter errors are left on the word `self`.

I've tried disabling autosave but it didn't help

I don't want to have to disable the server since I like IntelliCode, which requires it

Is there any way to either fix the issue or just mute these errors?

Comment: It sounds like you might be seeing an issue with the MS Python Language Server - it'd be great if you can raise it on their GitHub Issues at https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/ - so the team can take a look? I'm glad to hear you like IntelliCode for Python! Thanks
Mark Wilson-Thomas
Visual Studio IntelliCode Team

Comment: Is it inside a `dataclass`?

Comment: Nah sorry man, ended up using something else and forgot about this